# Let X = {1,2,3}, define a function k: X→X that is one-to-one and onto but is not the identity function on X

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can anyone give me insight on what "but is not the identity function on X" means?

I just started studying onto and one-to-one functions and this portion of the question confused me. Any insight would be much appreciated!

Comment: The identity function is the function $f:X\to X$ such that $f(x)=x$ for all elements $x$ of $X$. In this particular case it's the function with $f(1)=1, f(2)=2$, and $f(3)=3$.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that a function that is one-to-one and onto a finite set to itself is called a permutation, and we often shorthand permutations as strings.  The permutations of $\{1,2,3\}$ are written as $123,132,213,231,312,321$.  Any of the permutations above except the first would satisfy your desired properties once written in a more proper format.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
f(1) &=& 1\\
f(2) &=& 3\\
f(3) &=& 2
\end{array}$$